# Does Spark Config Override Spark Session

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I am using Airflow to create a DAG to run a spark job. In the DAG I am setting the `spark_conf` (executor memory, driver memory, and maxResultSize) for my use case.
I received a GC memory error so, as I was reviewing the python code I noticed a spark session was being created where `maxResultsSize` was being set in the config.
My question is if this would override my `spark_conf` that I set in the Airflow DAG?

Comment: which operator are you using?

Comment: @Jonathan I am using the `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator`